# Query Hive remotely using shell

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, remote-server, hiveql

Let's imagine I have access to an Hive datawarehouse, I can query it using some webservice. The problem is that I cannot automate the query using this service, so I would like to be able to query Hive from an external script (that I would be able to automate).

For now, I've only seen people running Hive on their local machine and querying it, I was wondering if it was possible to do it remotely ? If yes, how ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you are asking if there are ways to connect to hive from a remote machine?

You could install hive client (beeline) on any remote machine and connect to hive via jdbc.

Take a look here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this, is to deploy the client configuration of hadoop/yarn on the remote machine. If the remote cluster is secured with firewalls and kerberos, you will need access to those first. After that it's just a matter of starting up a hive shell or committing a job submit to Yarn.

When you use Cloudera, you might be able to add the host to the cluster and install a "gateway" role for yarn and hive on the target machine. This is very straight-forward and requires just a few minutes of work.

Alternatively using the JDBC connector should also work, as stated in Facha's answer.